# mount laptop hard drive disk from live DVD

Tags: mount, data-recovery, fstab, fdisk, livedvd

I was following [directions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14369/change-or-reset-windows-password-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/) for changing the password for Microsoft Windows (on a laptop) with chnptw, but when I navigated to `/mnt` and `/media` the directories were empty -- I believe that the `/mnt` directory had a link to the optical drive.

The (old and dated) directions say to navigate to `/media`.

Has this been changed for Ubuntu 14.04 live DVD?

Answer (score 1):

I know the current LTS live versions of Linux Mint (Ubuntu-based) normally mounts to `/media/mint/[directory]`. Ubuntu's should be similar, but it's easy to check:

Iif the drive is mounted somewhere, you can go to a terminal and run `lsblk` to see what partitions are mounted where.

`mount` shows similar info, but has more than just physical drives/partitions.

Or if you've got Disks (gnome-disks, in package `gnome-disk-utility`) installed it shows you where things are mounted too, and can try to mount & unmount them also.

Note:

Most live systems do not automatically mount HD partitions, there's often a one-click way to mount them from the File Manager (whichever it is, Nautilus, Thunar, pcmanfm, Nemo, Caja...) usually click on the drive from a "places" or "devices" list.

Or use Disks as mentioned above.

Or use a terminal & `mount` yourself (heh heh)